# Call to method onSearchRequested() in the same activity that handles search requests causes duplication in activity stack

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I have an activity that handles search requests with the SearchManager and it's working just fine.  Let's call this activity MySearchActivity.java.  The problem is that within this activity, I have a button that invokes the search request dialog with a call to onSearchRequested().

If MySearchActivity.java is the current task in the activity stack and the user taps the icon within this activity that calls onSearchRequested(), this activity is re-launched on top of itself.  So within the activity stack, I have two of the same activities on top of each other.

I don't want to use android:noHistory in the manifest for this activity, and can't find any other suitable flags for what I'd like to accomplish.

I would like that if the user taps the icon in MySearchActivity.java which invokes the call to onSearchRequested(), that the activity not duplicate itself in the stack.

I know I'm probably overlooking something or making this more complicated than it really is....any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solution you probably have to set launch mode to "singleTop" for activity (e.g android:launchMode="singleTop"). Here is the further explenation @[documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). Good luck!